# Advanced Custom Fields Sorting Order for a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Advanced custom fields extension in my wordpress project. to show some custom content on a specific page, I have about 20 custom field in one page and i called them in theme file by like this way..

```
<?php if(get_field('name1') != ""): ?>
            <div class="row-hardware">
            <div class="partner-left"><img src="<? the_field('image1'); ?>" /></div>
            <div class="partner-right">
                <?php the_field('description1'); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

               <?php if(get_field('name2') != ""): ?>
            <div class="row-hardware">
            <div class="partner-left"><img src="<? the_field('images2'); ?>" /></div>
            <div class="partner-right">
                <?php the_field('description2'); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I called them for every single field, I saw in Advanced Custom fields it has drag and drop sorting area in admin area, but How can i call them as like sorting on theme file frontend.
is there any good solution ?

here i have attached images

thanks

[image]

Comment: you mean something like [get_fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_fields/) or [get_field_objects](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field_objects/)?

Comment: Is it possible to filter with field type. ? like i only want to show images type and text type,

Comment: [get_field_objects](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field_objects/) => `$field['type']`

Comment: Thanks if I only want to show all images and description field, that are images type and Wysiwyg Editor then what Should I do, as $field['type'] will only return type, but i need value of type. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (Not tested)

Note the `<div class="clear"></div>`. Add this to CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$fields = get_field_objects();
$i = 0;

if ($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field) {
        if (substr($field_name, 0, 5) == 'image' || substr($field_name, 0, 11) == 'description') {
            if (($i % 2) == 0) {
                echo '<div class="row-hardware">';
                echo '<div class="partner-left"><img src="'.$field['value'].'" /></div>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class="partner-right">'.$field['value'].'</div>';
                echo '<div class="clear"></div></div>';
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Last but not least. It's not that dynamic, but if your number of fields change constantly you should consider to create a custom post type.

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 19; $i++) : ?>
<div class="row-hardware">
    <div class="partner-left"><img src="<?php the_field('image'.$i); ?>" /></div>
    <div class="partner-right"><?php the_field('description'.$i); ?></div>
<div class="clear"></div></div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: @ShamimAhmed in your afc image fields, do you have `Image Url` as return value? Also add a div who clear the floating at the end of every `row-hardware`. See my update.

Comment: which fields are missing? did you rename image to image1 and description to description1 ?

Comment: @ShamimAhmed ok my fault..see the change with `substr`

Comment: @ShamimAhmed can you post the html source of the page somewhere?

Comment: @ShamimAhmed ok I hope it works now..check the new code. It is a lot cleaner.

Comment: thanks Is it possible to sort ordering Alphabetically by name value ?

Comment: @ShamimAhmed Which name value? You mean Field Name?

Comment: @ShamimAhmed see my update. This assumes that you have 19 different rows. Perhaps it's the best to setup a custom post type if the number changes.